# Need ideas and testing a new encryption method I developed

Tags: encryption

I developed a new method of encrypting information. It does not comply with standard methods of encryption and was custom made to encrypt info stored in session cookies.

It basically works like this:
-It takes a standard 72 char string as it's IDENTITY or password. There could be more than a million variations of this.
It then uses a pre-defined set of randomly generated variations of text and uses that to hide the actual content. However, it has special chars hidden in each enrypted line to help identify how to decrypt it.

My reason for posting here is to see if anyone here could (a) crack it or (b) give me some advice on how to make it better.

I am not too reluctant to give too much info yet as this is still in aplha stage and not the finished project.

Here is an example. It is the 50 US states in random order. Please note that even if I keep the same order, each time it will look different. To prove that, I will run it twice with the same order used:

### First Run:

> H39pwxMnczu+#u!?:IeQAAeSPrjJFRZ84#zma-XbMaU7#F|Bm!6o3qgnJ3 cFIoTYNS|dAfVa
>   ibes!zd!O-e4sxx8yOo!?hTvK-f6htqlRxT?pV3CT--l4vU#7TInYV-WXNFil-t3+tG+:9b5X
>   ?9#2Ncfn8AUim!3LZw#s5YRqF5Xfwm1:sCO?B90ViBQkmW?MlHn1h4Pd5AU8Lw QYwzr8IxhB
>   0r!mccmccmffmRzbapQ_dSjm+9#5jRR_IlqvWjY:Z9RfiABL_Rp#Dp!DyP?HiAB#9+HXRp?1x
>   SHjCpl+lvLvKVECH#bY+jn?T_-:1T7M#x?4uQ!bsJglVmc5dHN79HUF58|sTVDIp#jN__8tIk
>   ?5ErfVd2N9TgcR3pWE#Dw98FYnUT9BHlBolV:mPFYnHw5P69BmJhWo|fYYL25P?rguINWY+f4
>   P?6QBXUxyYg3iWNpVL2FoBd-s UaqyAaOc M#2xd6ewglq??MZe4nD-#UnW3H6Fa?TIAdegkd
>   ERM?yyKtW_IydIOm77ia:9ao8 o#RcB8u_G3Jwox-K?0IC#S22GG0wQH-hfbptWSCCKo0Noaj
>   SRnCpwIzQv2CwvtH_Qt2RUT9ms#TDY9#Jb9J88m_V5xmQL_Gnj_9kO5JiRYVN0pY?YW_RnI9g
>   rDVUGkUuEg76dDXVawq|SImE8MyKKDDmar+|vHh93?y88SwmFwtYvzCNEA52n:eCfu1PGgH k
>   RO6ZAV7VO3S:3WWz+1LGzlb+o#!+:xyL3BKA1jIHArAd+K#4:5k2 Oi2Og2F|:DI+fxXL|f7G
>   DmqBiMZv2277kCjE# 6JPAorUURxk+xNB p?ew!cnuTz?GMqO8v63tJ7Mu TGoENfSN6Q4C7Y
>   !VMBYFY5YLadz0!TnjMrVA8Sr2rFdML-zR45:9m59i5e zg8dx0+T x?1LP79cFTnj:mc93w
>   S#?vL+v+i+mNXmV:W4ckvwjGMJRcQKAntLxgIH9KMWJQFTVb!Vxhlp9ELJ_7FVBU2YD:gJbAL
>   omUd_SFpmR_dXC RwigvHF67DObZdOZ-O_f6#egP4lMfP?BHzJZEiMj!bdEZQSfTsRBbWrzm:
>   09!mIINcG-n??B1-jQfdA#_lp|tG++M9jpedAJ_mpzd+P 7Ws5MD4Y#+p4dP97n0?HYR4!0Z+
>   cEtiKjA:6hfp+#D2ClS-2eH9e1dDsNZ7mN5vwR- a:EZ6j|3Py#I3ivk0hfp1|KIglp-Jz-d
>   |c9O:#Ue5Mk575P004EY 9QKC!5 cQ0ysIGgp46Z-r0 ZQyEIPLVo-HZXLN0RRiYbAYV0S_ZV
>   xXY#8SAwW ZB?Sr4OcL!ncpl+#m_W?iL5HAJ3 Z0Jol9|DyC-A80UgCm7zmr_8QMOpDmHE4XF
>   :r7:LlgSvzJuKm6oXy8r#XRMaJvNsnydX?N-rtt4Y73YsrwIXsf6nKoYf7Zc be:dj0ppKKh#
>   G-f8w8PPb-Z-oHp:BPAVDj-MHvSZyp0_E8k mwZvLLp?30AaFCUO!DUZ+h:#OS637Am6UXKUu
>   TcWQAUyQ:VJKv94zus2X9tn88p3vD34tgr2iupAwD+INKoMQuc?mXeZoouyKDohTm6 JoveXP
>   dP27Gb4iLdZ51w7YDr8#XTdisjQGrYII#BnX6P532?KH2r0LtS?D:nN6Q:2-_2lGDcZU3THX3
>   wAt9|j:9:OyvSwM8GmuFAN0zbg:eGXTUaknggG!bAgcqU62PgrkaxGCTXCtGlrF|lGq:XdUT1
>   np1lj08kyIC-qNcOpxAwjxS9Y|#A6g-dNJgxiDx+K6W?vp3jqpplpSDvTI:49N|16NHZNs :i
>   qA_92j6!YML9jMMF mv|b5NSS K97Seq|8JXS+5b2 zvmzf c+BCc qMmr|vyhVgc+xLhn_Oh
>   3O!9IS|9Vj9BY_G J-0: !zf!ZIGLjuq|Reqq9q4fuPt8vm0y5G0#H0p78zeYE6eGd3O sO+5
>   4KxCIUCRCe614E_K 5aI72VD297P BMP76eD|1VqjmRP uXjdF3jP|NiCBPoVUKmx1QT_skiB
>   rD_IvYESiE::6th4CKM67?:hNStD1:g _xH_jdY54#+y8YK+snh2|zyf0:we UtwCKHhcI:jc
>   j4vbZ0hkYSkr2!Vq5ua+rxT4mHUxGtLYEEXXxeTAmzsyG_vL4hX:xeArSKJq8ldm4ij2qklrx
>   848Tf?I76s?TZVDsSW7NW M6om3j+E6|jiIbOR_+5uD4US?14G|Nb9dD 961hLBj1zsb!0bZo
>   QefvLrM!sP:OmqqRRsHuCNV_BPG0O83RXsHCapIbJ75#N8czeJx5as7LxiFv#5cVydKyrsPL3
>   gJxaabTzbY!7LSCNsZ-XhBFrl1dbtleLgsPmrHP7tK2VStDTs qsJ07ckxwul2mwXg_Xrr8nw
>   glo3YkbTQnzTQJ5evtzc8gDulM0o qF_std?h TFlgqwTrKm_Fd-74j73gJwzrK0gloYJteVS
>   aHDL7A+ZHlFLIygly8nkKBqQjNUQF8 sC48pgqJDq|?FV+ih-nsjh#Bw#NN1AhGL+Jm78BqAw
>   H-U8Jyg7n:6ei#af:qF?erI6l?As8iefonU9nwI-l7As!IrRm-ajd3F|0NVM-sccAbZIMC6VF
>   JqWhZczdLcpfqn_5kNwuKe30yKP6e8|ZeqXO3k8Vn3CFkDB_ke??9qDMr8tfqpRvqkGhMe2XF
>   AAx7JTdlXYYSdVMdA1!NjHgS1RNdUI2AxCDcaJuS8iiwm#NuxeJcNK7jSuiDA2ZAj!lj+n7D_
>   -FQf::fvo9:1MM:YVuA0VxX-+yuhn+61y 4vyVddlx aIupDxQFMxyPtaVcX1!mhmZAmLxT5W
>   CC603Xv0n:CqhLd 9:1g3yFpS2CYaaOf8L2gtSFLjWTC2ay1:v1T0kTQ?WyRNn14Qv_zy5|6l
>   qSU9E92MC9hstXhHAA+Ssy 5-aSKejShBLyHdfFDC:C1WCRSpOvAx8|4zwjcV|M18b:PnBqmN
>   pGWHgmJUU3:sBt|6lSB+2?9tUMGCXG?mk?1_2MufcGW1XdiMDY7Td3#HckI!h+Qsp?SjNB3 ?
>   p97lhhHvpl7#E93wDTkoWeiCtCB6Ca9lMN:rjvVugE?IvmBjht_|wUQ1|XS#Xp9_agWo2gd5R
>   Ua9QU!j|UQ|G:tdALda+OaP-bthr|dmPLW9tc01_WBJj|OHIU9:Qk8o:kHm3CE95BP?W6ptd3
>   usPh|dRWdWftqwqtZ21#4R5O4+ 4#T2C?nkCjbSZMM#Ml5YqO-?q:HL?J|sT3h-#rQ9#gB09P
>   j4ehkYokoQUs2Gvb5GS?xv_Tmmis?wO1TrHY1r_txSAJG+C04nza5xZ:dH93a!C0G56X4#fAx
>   us:1SdYdh14#T2C?nkCjbSZMM#Ml5YqO-?q:HL?J|sT3h-#rQ9#gB09P5t4QK_wb3XZiO|ZFS
>   p4sHcceZElZvE+Nh:gUlQqEUQIWBswi931xdjFMGBpaCqrTM#1x9GXZdRJwBBjU3IUcpG!sHG
>   jmQbkkb??bb9aO4Chq4HvXq_jG:iZh5Uux5VWYxwa2+uT1n#iLmKCjmf6oGlwssJE0qHP+qtd
>   gJ-mTnvc?VoJrCXtG-fSg78_B!wfPCXJSactZKuggGNr5NT7S0MzS1J 0QQrhDvlxH?t 3V

### Second Run:

> GAG58FX0vFXjbXH-S#Np6aEPC6ekzwQvpbP0 3F8AihC9UdZ0+2of_70kfqv?KH-SQo5kyEAM
>   hjLKSsOShgSjjH3Grh|YMjqC6fwRji hY9v?aJZDunghjC FYvd#x8nxCm#theeFMuXMrhTlC
>   :dZNv3gLrJMp04uYXAL 5z3v#nkrCjDa c:oPi6 pPVY?fIsduoUp7T#mb9rYCUN2AvIr:epy
>   p1rJJrJJrhhr4HM!mtC6AQiYq 50jSC!Gt?6QcrfEjfGorwCll?s0UsnCdhG34 EY5sj0I7F
>   kxATb4J4aBae!wHoXJx0WnZdLl0pdP V_s9m17E:ex5b#3ok83maad-2pXIwxUXvNUEnnyLXH
>   AoRZTCJ2!T#4-c::ZcokDSyFgo#9TTlncSKkMCstgolM jnvB4sibSNV!O1Xdj884jdEpwRI7
>   hM1S#R|RM1GKrJlMx7uChoIdYQnZYMSSem96piXhBpqGB7EE3fpxv9Zjn|BOfB#FxLVShoI6h
>   Dz3ivvRAodwv4wlgZZrQm73U8BLYANr8dJQ0p!Lus76Cwj#SxJII!JxDKTnktxm#j27FCTFY7
>   RK#iHq4tlVDiqV3Mr73+VVhWnz6f2|#6yq#gFFBU61en7OrZ#DU#_T1KIV|CHz||N|3UaQcki
>   qSKpX6p:MgXacPBTjDqRS1|MytVmc??jcmdLh5r6m tywS8|h8_Sh apmSLq1AMaC+9bh Yv+
>   QJdvgr#rdpm76yyoGd8Zb#JVv7zG7uR8-LrN!OaNNXNiGEM?53CJoI8JHUJPf5za:BWa809sZ
>   CFg3J2sndTYYBTdm5Oh9WdFqlDC wO NCOF|SdC5aLf0|:1sAOFpu1Rt1LOfpkbjAVNQI1Ttn
>   PdjcQ1QWQy-wUagFcNgxQxV#G_x6_g3bHF3m8Jjfmgmp0ZaVTAA4OeAR 3RqJTgjc??jb2?v0
>   xL+B? B m3gyOgBCnPy:me40_ZZyiYBCM|zl7DA00nH8v EC4ozl7hDr|H:irBmLv9rCl?DB|
>   jSWhZYRNSoZh6Tko5ePqx8d+x9jOwJ9q9HyXm_YGGt!RGUsxUVOYqw622w8I2#y45KkjCzS++
>   ! vpssP#mwYBBcVoY1t:TnLqPzzv5mu#F1 QTnLxqy:5wVyYd9uKy1nsqY:wSyji79D-8diOs
>   XCV34ukN|9|WzyBUU0+ZU!i6!JbB:LS88L238 |CXRNP-lxppoMipVK6A9EpJx#r20jXCQkfC
>   u!e1W0uHKh2KRKdD-HW59Zf84MQ_CwD0qCdt?HVC94R_dw0XCl!T?:znt!rR44gLCb5|R9aft
>   s7RcsundeK|Y8u1xE7|gg7VUgLt2kQ8W?Pw--aO0-N!S3lq-hwizVe9k2yrI2iBEEVurPbz3k
>   cEXHAQK:TEdT-ZCkdpv:hT0n5d+r!ZxRb-rs:vvgNdW4l:pai-3CZfkNpdfoIDPu6Z-15aaxS
>   AcH!Y!JJCpCbHJOosE2NF+bc:MJSd!TAtkjoNIj2eewlovAdRTcAjFljX1SwAJdoyuNsW2wc9
>   Nd4brngbG+DCb+1NL1U-+BBAxDXbHX1cm1qzyWcwCXFiH1v30r4P-U3:CXXgS?dVPdM9pUU-Q
>   X+Qnb_IduieZkrnWkUAd4XQ?zC6Jzv22p8CgXA 4:Xz#8zylUpXkAC5|6VRvp:+JkUoF4X#iN
>   q7fgCpMgMH7rt7+?RCrn9HV5T7xUEw_bP1Uv9HHKgBmYbm A211PJLS_|S+Lj1ne2EYxwSW_s
>   ipqEg:X?!c-pYtxIgbtVG-VFMNct?xpiXTSLQcbfw?NPJgtGW4p#4zTJLZ-UFmPTvEt8mdb-Q
>   kuXTnNQz|asTNayvWFXJK v7TmmVBMp|Jp9un K!s0Xb0esN 5EnW|yF0UXotdAN#x+t9mtl
>   -Eb1J#-1|:18ylTE+ hZ!pmyIF6TxSr2lQWY+CY:Zrp8Vj-RSZo1lGRtIVmPyzdWV+?Dn4D5Z
>   !zupeZpspY0j?zc37puAR+LM+BRQg c34d1!8yziP94:2ntqeVJD8ynp1szKB6VXe_9gyZil5
>   hrp|wESsOSh6JjB8BGCBH?9:vxjxnhM1fO6naExgQCAu8RrA7Fx7iMCH16h9K|M8EsLrVY6:y
>   Zf#puO9hDFNPUqwJW0:SGmp2woALX-ufvV:SL8WhGt_1f ub2NScmQOPoYzJ4TlG2RcUJIhPS
>   _ObYH2 Jk72YU-LG1S+O-DkURITg547tg#NU#8GTe1OLyHhG4kzZt0VOnpJ1QMiVxW+aGJtcC
>   Fm7|tY1feJyc5ngtpeFPM6kjG54cQUzp!TNX_sv1m3:Y6UD!amHM_px mCMYp::vhNZMqex9j
>   VQ0qqPuIPYwuQeD2UDjGpKlrHZqXGwVY?QJWrtMIl|CdW8-RcGIQ_6u1e9hoQz#HGD1Prrn!H
>   WLqm:eKU2jtUkDEwAf1L2?I7xbe:gShmzfo2CgcUxL|jgqUmLhhetInURV|a_LSKVxjtDNna4
>   Qp73OmWkpry3wuxrveKyM-PLia5A3Hd#giIXzFe3PJqxEsTm+P2rNe6Euaa9_N0wvefCJiFCr
>   7:x!sRIUtHyZXI#:Gx4D97prCQ89mXZMD+?d+VesF:vPDblFyytLF6UdSI!84EBl9yIFKA4O
>   9F+3I6B#e65AEKQhDPrEDcbIVW9scy BcEnR?2ywFbhC2vpt2c:lf?HDudzNE0P-E2UiTnk46
>   GKir5CGmzJfE7FEBly6nQXfiH6PPv_6j5FsWa YK?HCPW6+dYc4#U+fK??FQVi+nyGnH1aFY
>   wc!:aa:PzUae88aBrc2zrAkqGXc|gOF5XwVfXr umGylJ4jxAL3TAX9+8k7e:yfPfIh:qAe10
>   2RIPO7LP|09zfg66O7gpSbDQ20?GEfW6Qg+B?TqUa+9GEEbrPz+RcCRfI2b?pD+rP4nNcdRj3
>   gJMzaz73_zlK2VlSALg qshMb7t5!UtlTQnZBm3qVcVrO3NtmwaeHA7BFJuJ2uLGezg4aXrs1
>   f mS+!RNg:xZ3OvGhIiLOARNN0j!8OK+ Kg620GbuOj!QDB+nKmcD0t44O|kAvBM?KIcL00TK
>   fK6QTTSc_QIMHA0?nU|w2!VqNq3R!hA2PExBz_w9KCKyC+ZxSOXEL3:i4 u+uDG6nKjN2KDWg
>   F_CF1GhM1FMvkGm4XmpGjdEZHA-xhmN4JQsgjdUVQPPx8zmU96pgRp5Vc|PidU6Jqpkf ylKs
>   gJ17?3TY3YHN?s5BurGPLhsVAl0AcgrHkJFKk3SdX MTYsJaVhR5wtlRmgDC? 5c8fG1US4!v
>   UW1j|o+|+jOHMrE68LsyYE33e4cOyS5k8xkWYnK3usy5r0kTpo:gt6yPu_55N0DdItdam+yy6
>   gJBma3L37mAcgrHkJFKk3SdX MTYsJaVhR5wtlRmgDC? 5c8fG1US4!vsBefg1n3ht7QlZOXS
>   bCYjqq#b?tbN?p FN-cyocxVu#HSLF-EncXQ?_290F3SJ--Gn5z69zAkwFF0S?Zn8Z aYzcBw
>   UahK||KUUKKUa5LDOTH_WkTK31PcyH!qt6Y4druSa8gt3Yo+OWnGkMw?da1LSppnBdQkWgG3k
>   R:rZbqHTDa:6Azhrq8Md OeBI::jAac!dc|xVOO Bq3A73+-yczUVq-fY3gnec5S7iorx|:4Y

As you can see, it looked different for the same order of 50 lines of text.

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Any encryption method which relies on the secrecy of the algorithm is flawed.  The attacker will always know the algorithm.  See [Kerckhoff's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_Principle) for a longer explanation.

It is absurdly easy to write an algorithm that you yourself cannot break, anyone can do it.  However, unless you are a professional cryptographer, a professional cryptographer will find it easy to break.  Have you tested your algorithm against differential cryptanalysis?  Do you even know what [differential cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis) is?

There are many excellent cyphers available already, suitable for many different purposes and with varying levels of complexity and security.  Don't reinvent the wheel; use an existing cypher.